# SharePoint 2013 - Page viewer web part (Windows File Share) Back / Forward Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-viewer-web-part

I am using office365/SharePoint online **Page Viewer Web Part** to show the windows file share. But I didn't find any way to go **backward and forward** in this page viewer file share web part. Only browser back button is working like that. I don't need the user to click on back / forward icons in the browser top left area.

Is there any way to achieve this back / forward in the page viewer web part itself. Or any other solution to achieve this?...

OR,

Instead of Back and Forward button, Can I show the windows explorer left navigation tree view on this page viewer web part..So that the users can go the areas wherever they can use the tree view to navigate through folders and files

Please advise..

Comment: how did you implement `Page Viewer Web Part` to show `Windows File Share`?

Comment: Edit the page viewer  webpart , select FOLDER and give the path. it works only on IE

Comment: If I give it C:/  THEN  will it list alll directory and files on the server??